# Get all integer values between two set of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two set of numpy.arrays like for example:

```
a = np.array([10, 25, 36, 56, 78], dtype=int)
b = np.array([15, 32, 45, 64, 89], dtype=int)
```

They represent the upper and lower limits of indices for some other dataset.
So, I want a pythonic way to get all values between a pair of elements from both sets, like, for the first elements I must get:

```
c = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], dtype=int)
```

and so on.
Is there a one-liner for that?

EDIT: I need it to come out as 1d-array. Sorry for not specifying that before.

```
c_all = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 25, 26, 27, ...], dtype=int)
```

Comment: How about `c = np.arange(a[0], b[0] + 1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ars =  [np.array(range(i,j+1),dtype=int) for i,j in zip(a,b)]
```

> Output:

```
[array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]),
 array([25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]),
 array([36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]),
 array([56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64]),
 array([78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89])]
```

and then you can slice it if you want:

`ars[0]` will give you: `array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])`

Answer (score 4):

Shortest way of doing this using list comprehension:

```
[np.arange(x, y + 1) for x, y in zip(a, b)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `numpy.arange()` as:

import numpy as np

```
l = []
l.append([np.arange(a[i], b[i]+1) for i in range(len(a))])
l

'''
Output:
[[array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]),
  array([25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]),
  array([36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]),
  array([56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64]),
  array([78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89])]]
'''
```